# mysql unhex() not working on linux server?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I use the following code to store user password into a mysql table with the password column being a `BINARY(20)` type:

```
$salted_hash = sha1($salt . $password);
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO foo(user, password) VALUES ('guest', UNHEX('%s'))", $salted_hash);
```

The select query to match password looks like:

```
$salted_hash = sha1($salt . $password);
$sql = sprintf("SELECT `userID` FROM `foo` WHERE `user`='guest' AND `password`=UNHEX('%s')", $salted_hash);
```

The code works fine when I connect to a web server running on a windows or mac machine. However, my production web host is a linux machine, and the `SELECT` is failing there.

I can only `phpMyAdmin` to my web host (mhpMyAdmin version 3.4.7.1). Through phpMyAdmin I execute the following query:

```
SELECT UNHEX('3530280EDB5AA715929266D1D6F0423ABC27B104')
```

The result displayed is the same number hex number `3530280EDB5AA715929266D1D6F0423ABC27B104`, which seems to indicate that the `UNHEX` function is not doing anything on linux.

If I execute the same query in [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) on Mac I get `50(ÛZ§fÑÖðB:¼'±`.

I'm not sure what's going on and where to look. I'm thinking either phpMyAdmin cannot display binary or there is indeed some problem with UNHEX(seems unlike) Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does `SELECT UNHEX(BINARY '3530280EDB5AA715929266D1D6F0423ABC27B104')` show?

Comment: It shows `3530280edb5aa715929266d1d6f0423abc27b104`meaning it's converting the hex string to lowercase. What would that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's a configurable setting: ["Show binary contents as HEX"](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#DisplayBinaryAsHex). I've tried your query in the same server...

```
SELECT UNHEX('3530280EDB5AA715929266D1D6F0423ABC27B104')
```

... but using two different clients. I can confirm that phpMyAdmin escapes binary output the way you've found. You can double check that the output is correct with:

```
SELECT HEX(UNHEX('3530280EDB5AA715929266D1D6F0423ABC27B104'))='3530280EDB5AA715929266D1D6F0423ABC27B104'
```

..., which should return 1, or running the original query with simple PHP script. To sum up: there's nothing wrong with `UNHEX()`.

*Most hosting services I've used actually allow external MySQL clients, you just need to enable it in the control panel. Make sure it's not the case. It's silly to use a dumb web client if you can connect with Sequel Pro.*

I suggest you do further debugging with your PHP code. It's not clear to me how you build the hash to match (do you retrieve the salt in some other query?).

Comment: The salt is hardcoded in my php script. Like so: `$salt = 'mmm... salty';

Comment: Well, one of the goals of using a salt is that duplicate passwords generate different hashes... But it should not affect current issue anyway. As I said: further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading this post is because none of the above solutions worked for you (as for me).

I've solved by using stored procedures...

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SearchMessage`(IN code_to_search VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE UPPER(UNHEX(SUBSTRING(hex_field,25))) like CONCAT('%',UPPER(TRIM(text_to_search)),'%') COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
END
```

Hope it helps.